# FCM set a fixed instance id?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app that will only be used by me. Is it possible to set a fixed FCM instance id? I want to skip the work of communicating the dynamic instance id to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need to use the instance ID assigned to the device by the SDK, and keep it up to date in case it changes for that device.